# Local directory as SVN repository

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

I created my first project in eclipse and using SVN for version control, as I don't want to commit my code to any server, I created the local repository in my machine and using it for version control, everything is running perfectly fine but I am wondering where does the project gets stored because I can see only the configuration files in my local repository folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand exactly but did you try `svn info YOUR_PROJECT_DIRECTORY`? I think the `URL:...` (line 3) will show the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The SVN repository does not contain your project files in an human-readable way. For more information, you should read the "Subversion Repository" [section](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.basics.html) of the SVN book.